# Increment the selector name

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have a form that is collecting personal info on family members.  There is a button that that allows for additional form fields (SSN1, SSN2 and so on) I have a function that formats the SSN. When I try to add a counter to it so that if the user adds additional SSN fields the function will also format the additional fields.

```
        var counter = 1;
        $("##SSN"+counter).keyup(function() {
                counter++;
                var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
                var newVal = '';
                var sizes = [3, 2, 4];

                for (var i in sizes) {
                  if (val.length > sizes[i]) {
                    newVal += val.substr(0, sizes[i]) + '-';
                    val = val.substr(sizes[i]);
                  }
                  else
                    break;       
                }

                newVal += val;
                this.value = newVal.substr(0,11);
            }).focusout(function(){
                showRequiredDatabaseCheck();

            });
```

Comment: `##SSN` really is that one? one `#` was not enough?

Comment: I would highly recommend just using a single class for all of the SSN instead of IDs and incrementing the number.

Comment: This is on a Coldfusion page so the additional # is needed.

Comment: @user2072347: If Coldfusion is, server-side, replacing the `##` with a single `#` and if you are trying to focus on the client-side functionality then it would be best to separate the two.  The question above is entirely about JavaScript (using jQuery), so when attempting to diagnose issues you'd better serve yourself by examining the resulting client-side code so you can separate Coldfusion from the equation.  Having said that... What exactly isn't working here?  I don't see where you're describing a problem or asking a question.

Comment: @David: the problem that I am having is client side. When the user adds additional fields that increment by 1 I also want the script above to increment so that each added SSN field will be formatted by the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers aren't dynamic like this.  The code to attach this handler runs *once*, when the page loads, and finds only the matching elements at that time.  Since the elements are being added dynamically during the interaction with the page, it sounds like event delegation is useful here.

Specifically the use of jQuery's `.on()`.

To make it easier, we should also remove the `counter` (since its only purpose here is to identify an `id`) and use a `class` instead.  Give your inputs a common `class`, such as `ssn-input`:

```
<input type="text" class="ssn-input" />
```

(Or however you build your inputs, this is just an example.)

For your event handler, instead of attaching it directly to the inputs themselves (since they don't exist yet when the page first loads), attach them to a common parent element that's already there.  Any parent element will do, but for this example we'll go all the way up the hierarchy to `document`:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.ssn-input', function() {
    // the event handler logic you already have
});
```

In this case the second argument to `.on()` is a kind of filter to use when the event is handled.  Since the event is attached to `document`, *all* `keyup` events which bubble up to that level will be caught by this handler.  When the optional filter is used (here it's `'.ssn-input'`), the handler will ignore any events which don't originate from that matching filter.

So in this case the one event handler should cover all of your SSN inputs as you add more to the page.

Comment: Thank you.  The explanation was very helpful.